# AS3 goToAndStop() description coding

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, switch-statement

I am having trouble coding a .htmlText description appear after a `goToAndStop()`, I am also not even really sure if this is the right place to be putting the code... Any and all feed back will be greatly appreciated.

code:

```
stop();

inst_brandOne.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_4);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop("agua");


    switch (evt.target.name) {
        case "agua" :
            description.htmlText = text10;
            break;
    }
    var text10:String  = "<b>DESCRIPTION. </b>";

}
```

I would like to have my description appear when you user is taken to the "agua" section...

Thanks for looking, I'm really struggling here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Move variable defintion before switch statement.

2a. Refer to the event object as 'event' instead of 'evt':

```
function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop("agua");

    var text10:String  = "<b>DESCRIPTION. </b>";


    switch (event.target.name) {
        case "agua" :
            description.htmlText = text10;
            break;
    }
```

}

and/or:

2b. Get rid of the switch statement altogether:

```
function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop("agua");

    var text10:String  = "<b>DESCRIPTION. </b>";

    description.htmlText = text10;

    }
```

}

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but still not working. I'm getting a compiler error on the  - switch (evt.target.name) { - line... "Access of undefined property evt."

Comment: 1. do you have an object in on stage with an instance name of 'inst_brandOne? 2. If yes, when you click on it, is the function called (add something like a trace('yep, definitely being called'); statement in the function and check your output to confirm)? 3. Are you sure evt.target.name is 'agua'? Do a trace(evt.target.name) to find out for sure. 4. On the frame you've labelled aqua, do you have a dynamic/input textbox with the instance name of 'description'?

Comment: 1. Yes "inst_brandOne" is a button leading to the frame "agua" 

2. Yes, the button works and does what its supposed to. 

3. I think that this is the issue! I'm not even sure evt.target.name is the correct code, I had recycled the switch line from a simpler page also using descriptions.

4. Yes that frame has a textbox, (on its own layer) 

very cool of you to help me, thanks again

Comment: Cool cool. Edited the answer, taking into consideration the compiler error. One of those pieces of code should work. Just make sure that your textbox has its instance name set to 'description' (it'll be in the properties tab). Check out Learning ActionScript 3.0 - it's a nice book for learning how programming works, in Flash and in general.

Comment: Got rid of the switch statement and it works!!! Thank you very much for all your help, ya saved the day! cheers :))

Answer (score 0):

Your function creates a variable called "event" but in your code you reference that variable as "evt".

Pick one. In my opinion "event" is superior. Not a fan of shortened words. Thy dcrs rdblty. (Thye decrease readability)